# Regex for replacing two keywords with placeholders where 1 could be part of another

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Following URL's main content is editable for admins: http://www.vroomvroomvroom.com/terms-and-conditions/united-states/advantage/

It has 2 keywords which need to replaced with placeholders. These keywords could occur 0 to n times. Admin know these keywords during editing of content.

Task is to prepare a regex which could replace these 2 keywords with placeholders, which are:

1. [COMPANY_NAME] e.g.: VroomVroomVroom.com or RentalCarmomma.com
2. [CUSTOMER_SERVICE_EMAIL] e.g.: info@vroomvroomvroom.com or help@vroomvroomvroom.com

Here challenge is that 1st keyword could be part of 2nd keyword, which makes it hard to replace via simple replace function. Can somebody help me in preparing such a regex for javascript.

FYI: Text is HTML not simple text.

**[Update]**

Currently I am using something like:

```
$(".cms-editor").html().replace(/vroomvroomvroom.com/ig, "[COMPANY_NAME]").
```

And this is not useful because it can replace part of other keyword `[CUSTOMER_SERVICE_EMAIL]` and then I can't replace 2nd keyword with its placeholder

Comment: Could you improve your title? "Regex for specific issue" is not something anyone is going to search for. Also, the admin link you're giving us isn't helpful. once the content on that site changes, that part of your question becomes useless.  Please help us help you by including all the information we need ot solve your problem in the question itself.  Second, could you show us sample inputs, how they *should* match, as well as how they match currently?

Comment: This is public link. For admins the specific div converts to editable text via WISWIG editor. About incorrect matching: if [COMPANY_NAME] is  VroomVroomVroom.com and [CUSTOMER_SERVICE_EMAIL] is info@VroomVroomVroom.com than it becomes info@[COMPANY_NAME], which is wrong. And If replace [CUSTOMER_SERVICE_EMAIL] first than also similar could happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "vroomvroomvroom.com info@vroomvroomvroom.com";
str.replace(/(^|[^@])vroomvroomvroom\.com/ig, "$1[COMPANY_NAME]");
```

Result is...

> [COMPANY_NAME] info@vroomvroomvroom.com

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e3zf4/6/)

---

### Explanation:

- `^` Matches the beginning of the text
- `[^@]` Matches anything that is not an @ symbol

So the two combined with the `|` (or operator) will match either the beginning of the text, or anything that's not an @ symbol.

It's also necessary to use a back reference ("`$1`[COMPANY_NAME]") in the replacement string, otherwise the character that was not an @ symbol will also be replaced. The back reference puts this char back again.

Also note that I escaped the dot in ".com", the dot matches any character except new lines, so it must be escaped with a backslash. Without escaping it would have matched strings like "vroomvroomvroom_com" where the underscore could be any other character.

Comment: Thanks. It sort of works, but not completely. It replace the complete line having keyword with placeholder. Try following javascript at [this URL](http://www.vroomvroomvroom.com/terms-and-conditions/united-states/advantage/): `$("#ContentMain").html($("#ContentMain").html().replace(/(^|[^@]+)vroomvroomvroom\.com/ig, "[COMPANY_NAME]"))`

Comment: @iMatoria I just tested your fiddle, but I can't see the problem, the output is similar to mine.

Comment: In my example source string is: `str = 'Some intial text VroomVroomVroom.com info@vroomvroomvroom.com Some ending text'`, and output is: `str = '[COMPANY_NAME] info@vroomvroomvroom.com Some ending text'`. But, output which I am seeking is: `str = 'Some intial text [COMPANY_NAME] info@vroomvroomvroom.com Some ending text'`.

Comment: Thanks. I think its almost done. Now the character immediately before [COMPANY_NAME] is been removed. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3zf4/5/)**

Comment: @iMatoria I've updated my answer and fiddle,  I've included an explanation.